# javascript dynamic adding mutiple sets of textbox and mutiply all of them

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my textbox dynamic and able to calculate the value entered(length*width). So if I press add textbox once and enter a set of value it is supposed to calculate an area, if I press it 2 times and enter 2 sets of value it should return 2 calculated area. Right now i cant even calculate any value and im not sure why. Can someone help me on this? Thankssss!!! below is my code

This is my html

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="field_div">
<input type="button" value="Add TextBox" onclick="add_field();">
</div>
</div>
<p><button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><br>
<p id="Result">
</body>
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
function add_field(){
var total_text=document.getElementsByClassName("input_text");
total_text=total_text.length+1;
document.getElementById("field_div").innerHTML=document.getElementById("field_div").innerHTML+"<p id='input_text"+total_text+"_wrapper'><input type='text' class='input_text' id='length"+total_text+"' placeholder='Length'><input type='text' class='input_text' id='width"+total_text+"' placeholder='Width'><input type='button' value='Remove' onclick=remove_field('input_text"+total_text+"');></p>";
}


function remove_field(id){
document.getElementById(id+"_wrapper").innerHTML="";
}

 function calculate(){
 var length =  document.getElementById("Length").value;
 var width =  document.getElementById("Width").value;
 var area = length*width;
 document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = area;
 }


 </script>
```

-------------------------------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------------------

Below is the working code but it is just able to calculate the last pair of textbox

Javascript code

```
function add_field(){
var total_text=document.getElementsByClassName("input_text");
total_text=total_text.length+1;

document.getElementById("field_div").innerHTML=document.getElementById("field_div").innerHTML+"<p id='input_text"+total_text+"_wrapper'><input type='text' class='input_text' id='length"+total_text+"' placeholder='Length'><input type='text' class='input_text' id='width"+total_text+"' placeholder='Width'><input type='button' value='Remove' onclick=remove_field('input_text"+total_text+"');></p>";
}

function remove_field(id){
document.getElementById(id+"_wrapper").innerHTML="";
}

function calculate(){
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; ){
var length =  inputs[i].value;
var width =  inputs[i+1].value;
var area = length*width;
i = i + 2;
}
document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML += '<br>' + area;
}
```

html code

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="field_div">
<input type="button" value="Add TextBox" onclick="add_field();">
</div>
</div>
<p><button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><br>
<p id="Result">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property will force the recreation of the element. As a result there will not be any previous value in the input boxes.

Instead of using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) you have to append the element by [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to retain the inputs value. You have to use [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create the element. You can set all the required attributes for the element by using [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

**Working Code Example:**

```js
function add_field(){
  var total_text=document.getElementsByClassName('input_text');
  total_text=total_text.length+1;
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.setAttribute('id', 'input_text'+total_text+'_wrapper');
  var input1 = document.createElement('input');
  input1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input1.setAttribute('class', 'input_text');
  input1.setAttribute('id', 'length'+total_text);
  p.appendChild(input1);

  var input2 = document.createElement('input');
  input2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input2.setAttribute('class', 'input_text');
  input2.setAttribute('id', 'length'+total_text);
  p.appendChild(input2);

  var btn = document.createElement('input');
  btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  btn.setAttribute('value', 'Remove');
  btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'remove_field("input_text'+total_text+'")');
  p.appendChild(btn);

  document.getElementById("field_div").appendChild(p);
}

function remove_field(id){
  document.getElementById(id+'_wrapper').innerHTML = '';
}

function calculate(){
  var answer = 0;
  document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = '';
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
  for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; ){
    var length =  inputs[i].value;
    var width =  inputs[i+1].value;
    var area = length*width;
    i = i + 2;
    document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML += 'Answer '+ ++answer +') ' + area + '<br>';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="field_div">
  <input type="button" value="Add TextBox" onclick="add_field();">
</div>
</div>
<p><button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button></p>
<p id="Result"></p>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but the code does not work if i need to calculate 2 area

Comment: so are you able to help me if i want more than 2 area to be calculated?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer, what if you left the previous two input empty then add another two......which the calculate button should take into consideration?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer, should the button calculate only the last pair of input?

Comment: if user click 3 times there will be 3 set of textbox(input), then i will need 3 area/answer(output)

Comment: it should calculates all pair value

Comment: @NoobProgrammer, I think you should have separate button for each group...

Comment: is it possible to only have a button? because it will be weird if i add separated button. And i might need to calculate 5 area at once, must i click 5 different button

Comment: @NoobProgrammer, try it now.....but the logic is little bit different, without using any id.

Comment: still does not work, it only display the last pair of area

Comment: @NoobProgrammer, I have updated the answer. Please note the significant changes.......thanks.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!! btw is it possible to also display number beside the output like 
Answer 1) 10 
Answer 2) 22
Answer 3) 100
btw sorry for the late reply was on holiday.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer, you are most welcome. I have updated the answer with the string representation you mentioned....please check.....thanks.

Comment: Hi Mamum, i have a add on to the code of yours above but i cant seem make the code work, can you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424579/javascript-dynamic-adding-mutiple-drop-down-list?noredirect=1#comment87863994_50424579

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to modify it according to your need

```js
 
function add_field(){
var total_text=document.getElementsByClassName("input_text");
total_text=total_text.length+1;
document.getElementById("field_div").innerHTML=document.getElementById("field_div").innerHTML+"<p id='input_text"+total_text+"_wrapper'><input type='text' class='input_text' id='length"+total_text+"' placeholder='Length'><input type='text' class='input_text' id='width"+total_text+"' placeholder='Width'><p><button onclick='calculate("+total_text+")'>Calculate</button><p id='Result"+total_text+"'></p><br><input type='button' value='Remove' onclick=remove_field('input_text"+total_text+"');></p>";
}


function remove_field(id){
document.getElementById(id+"_wrapper").innerHTML="";
}

 function calculate(id){

 var length =  document.getElementById("length"+id).value;
 var width =  document.getElementById("width"+id).value;
 var area = length*width;
 document.getElementById("Result"+id).innerHTML = "Result ="+area;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="field_div">
<input type="button" value="Add TextBox" onclick="add_field();">
</div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: is it possible to have only 1 calculate button for 2 or more pair value? if not it is kinda weird

Comment: Yep @NoobProgrammer certainly

Comment: okayyy so are you able to help me with this? anyways thanks in advance

Comment: @NoobProgrammer you try it yourself, in case you need any help ask me

Comment: sure! i am trying on my hand too :D can you upvote my question? i think i need more reach out for others to help me